# Function running in an dynamic e-mail

Tags: php, dynamic, styling

I'm trying to have a line appear dynamically in a confirmation e-mail using PHP.

```
    //E-mail Alert Formatting
        $submission = date('D M d g:i a');

        $originalDate = $DateNeededInHand;
        $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));

        $now = time(); // or your date as well
        $due_date = strtotime($newDate);
        $datediff = abs($now - $due_date);
        $urgency = round(((($datediff / 60) / 60) /24),0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

    //Not Working
        function urgent($urgency) {
            if ($urgency <= 2) {
                echo '<div style="font-weight:bold; color:red;">URGENT!</div>';
            }
        }

------------------ ^ In PHP document ^ v In HTML document v ------------------

    <p><b>Submission: </b>'.$submission.'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.urgent($urgency).'</p>
```

And it's not displaying the dynamic bit.

Comment: What does `$urgency` evaluate to? Why is there stray HTML in your PHP block?

Comment: That's the html that I am using to try and insert the PHP, they are not in the same document. And $urgency is if there is less than 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

you can't put php in an html document. you can put html in a php document. So first your bottom code block needs to be in a php file. then your code needs to look like this:

```
<p><b>Submission: </b><?php echo $submission.'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.urgent($urgency); ?></p>
```

Comment: They are in two separate documents.

Comment: It's the function that's not working, I'm not trying to get the submission displayed but the 'URGENT!' if it's less than two days.